# General advice on tracking an object's changes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an option menu where a user can change the application's settings. I need to track the changes. There is a DONE button, I want to make changes to the data model only when the button is pressed.

My question is, I am not sure the best way to track the changes. I don't want to introduce a giant if blocks in the doneButtonPressed button. Any general advice?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the generic answer is: add callback to your controls in your options screen. 
For example if you are using UISlider, then you have to customize it slightly. Probably create a subclass, that would receive touch events and then you redirect them to the delegate. OR you can use this one: [RCSwitch](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/)

If you are using UIButton's then it's even easier: just add action to it.

After that you can create method like:

```
-(void) controlDidChange:(UIView*) control {
   //mark changed items here   
}
```